# How to use python ctypes to define an undefined symbol

Tags: python, linker, shared-libraries, ctypes, extern

I would like to use a shared library (with python ctypes) which expects that some symbols are defined in the program that uses this shared library.

In the following example, `var` is defined in `test.c`, while `nm libadd.so` shows that `var` is undefined;

```c
/* libadd.c */
#include <stdio.h>

extern int var;

int add(int a, int b) {
    return (a + b + var);
}
```

```
gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fpic libadd.c
gcc -shared -o libadd.so libadd.o
```

```
/* test.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include "libadd.h"

int var = 1;

int main(void) {
    printf("%d", add(1,2));
    return 0;
}
```

```
gcc -L/path/to/libadd -Wall -o test test.c -ladd
```

Similarly, how to do this with python ctypes;

```
# test.py
from ctypes import *

#what to do to define var?

sharedlib = CDLL("sharedlib/libadd.so", mode = RTLD_GLOBAL)
print( sharedlib.add(1,2) )
```

```
OSError: sharedlib/libadd.so: undefined symbol: var
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to create a seperate shared library to define `var` and load this before `libadd.so`.

```
/* resolve.c */
int var = 1;
```

```
gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fpic resolve.c
gcc -shared -o resolve.so resolve.o
```

```
from ctypes import *

sharedlib = CDLL("sharedlib/resolve.so", mode = RTLD_GLOBAL)
sharedlib = CDLL("sharedlib/libadd.so", mode = RTLD_GLOBAL)
```

Comment: I guess that is the only way.

Comment: btw you could generate .so in one step: `gcc -shared -fPIC -o resolve.so resolve.c`.

Comment: Do you really need to load libadd with RTLD_GLOBAL?  It is unnecessary to make all symbols visible for all. I suppose it is only necessary for resolve.so.

Comment: Btw, this ingenious solution made my day. Let’s hope you will get the memory layout correct for all symbols - otherwise the debugging could become pretty funny:)

Comment: Or modify "*program that uses this shared library*" (*python*) by adding `int var = 1;` in one of its sources, and recompiling it :)